# When is the Richest Settler evaluated?

Tags: catan, catan-traders-and-barbarians

I've run into what I believe might be an edge case for the rules of the Traders and Barbarians expansion to The Settlers of Catan. I'm hoping someone might be able to clarify (preferably with reference to rules I might have missed), or at least give me some solid opinions!

Let's say we have two players, and player 1 has 15 gold while player 2 has 14 gold. So, at the start of this scenario, player 1 has the 'richest settler' card. Let's also assume that both players are one victory point from winning.

At the end of his turn, player 1 needs to move his caravan in such a way that he will traverse player 2's roads and thereby give player 2 some gold. This means that player 2 will - temporarily - become the richest settler. At the end of the turn, though, player 1 will collect 5 gold from delivering goods, which would give him back the richest settler card. He will also get a victory point for delivering goods.

**My question is - at what point is the richest settler evaluated?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The latest core [Settlers of Catan](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf) <sup>(link to PDF)</sup> rules state:

> If you have 10 or more victory points during your turn the game ends and you are the  winner! If you reach 10 points when it is not your turn, the game continues until any player (including you) has 10 points on his turn.

And the [Traders and Barbarians](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?TaB_Rules_051908.pdf) <sup>(link to PDF)</sup> scenarios state:

> The normal rules for The Settlers of Catan apply. The changes are described below.

Therefore, we can infer that the rules for determining the winner apply here too, and while the amount of victory points required may change, when the winner is calculated is unaffected.

Even though Player 2 will have more victory points, it is NOT their turn, so Player 1 will win as soon as he/she has the necessary points.