# Why should a player reveal his victory points if someone else wins?

Tags: catan

In the base Catan rule book it says 'keep victory points cards hidden until you have 10 points in your turn and you can declare victory. (You should also reveal them if someone else wins.)

Why should a player reveal his victory points if someone else wins?

Can you please clarify what this means?

Answer (score 13):

You should reveal everything when the game ends so that

1. You know who came second
2. You know all the bits end up back in the box
3. You know someone hasn't made a mistake and failed to claim victory.

The rules state.

> If you have 10 or more victory points during your turn the game ends and you are the winner.

Which can be interpreted to mean you don't have to 'say' you have won and people can keep rolling and building, but you are already the winner.

Though this is [controversial](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/808573/had-ten-points-failed-declare-victory). And [Here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21105/in-settlers-of-catan-if-you-have-unrevealed-victory-point-cards-that-would-make/21107#21107), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Catan/comments/45csxz/how_to_lose_catan_with_10_points/).

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was about to write up, except with a different link that I'll leave here for reference: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/21107/16063

Comment: @TheThirdMan a much better link. Thanks. Everyone Feel free to edit in more if you find them.

Comment: It also stating that the points in your hand counts if you are tracking scores between games.  I I have heard of tournaments where amount of point scored affected your placing.

Comment: @BrianMifsud Please note that "Thank you"-styled comments are actually discouraged for the purpose of keeping the information down to a usable minimum. Instead, if you feel like your question has been sufficiently answered, please consider accepting an answer, which doesn't only mark this question as solved, but also awards you and the answerer a small number of points!