# Can two VP cards be played at once in Catan?

Tags: catan

Weve just started playing this as a group and have a question on victory point cards.

One person was on 8 points but had two cards that state:

> 1 Victory Point.
>
> Reveal this card on your turn if, with it, you reach the number of points required for victory

Can the two cards be played together? I feel "no" as going from 8 points to 9 points isn't victory, only from 9 points to 10 points.

Answer (score 14):

In the [Catan Rules](https://www.catan.com/sites/default/files/2021-06/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf) on page 5 it says:

[image: Playing Development Cards: At any time during your turn, you may play 1 development card (put it face up on the table). That card, however, may not be a card you bought during the same turn (except for a victory point card, as described below)!]

[image: Victory Point Cards (Orange Frame): You must keep victory point cards hidden. You may only reveal them during your turn and when you are sure that you have 10 victory points—that is, to win the game. Of course, you can reveal them after the end of the game if someone else wins. You may play any number of victory point cards during your turn, even during the turn you purchase them.]

So following these rules, not only can you play multiple Victory Point Cards, you MUST play them together in order to achieve 10 victory points.
All other type of Development Cards you can only play once per turn.

Comment: You don't have to. It says "you may reveal", which leaves open the option of not using them for winning. The opposite would be really hard to monitor or enforce anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachu I meant that you can not play one in one turn and then the next turn the other one. If you play multiple VP cards you have to use them together.

Comment: yes, you don't play them one by one. But you also don't HAVE to play them the moment you will get 10 points. You can just choose not to play them (or just miscount, or forget or so).

Comment: uh in english "may only"  means that you cannot do it at any other point.

Comment: @paul23: The rules give an option to reveal them _after_ another player victory. So, _if_ you play them, you _may only_ play them to win the game. And if you haven't played them when another player reaches 10 VP, you can still reveal them and have them counted.

Comment: VP cards are not "played" in the same sense as other development cards; you have those points the moment you buy the card. Note how the rules refer to revealing them to show that you have 10 points (not playing them to earn points). So not revealing the cards wouldn't change anything; you've already won once you have 10 points. You'd just be hiding the fact that you've won for no reason. See more details [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33845/victory-point-cards-at-the-end-of-the-game?rq=1).