# Do you win a game of Catan even if you don't realize you have won?

Tags: catan

If someone "wins" the game and then all players count points and a different player realizes that if they had played their victory point, *they would have won*, who wins? The person who declared the win or the person who had enough points but didn't realize it, but figures it out when or after another person has declared victory. In other words, do you have to declare victory 'on your turn' to win? If your turn has ended, can you declare victory on someone else's turn?

Answer (score 11):

I have found reference to this in other posts, though I didn't see a question phrased as directly as this.

In reference to the online [Rules (PDF)](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf):

On page 5, you will find the following under "Ending the Game":

> If you have 10 or more victory points during your turn the game ends and you are the winner! If you reach 10 points when it is not your turn, the game continues until any player (including you) has 10 points on his turn.

There is no requirement of declaring victory (though in other parts of the rules it does use the phrase "claim victory" or something similar.

On the [online FAQ](http://www.catan.com/faq/4616-victory-conditions-what-if-someone-has-reached-required-number-victory-points-for-win) the question is addressed pretty directly:

> Victory Conditions - What if someone has reached the required number of victory points for a win but is unaware of it? Did this player win anyway?

With response:

> Yes. The game ends as soon as a player has reached the required number of victory points on his turn. If he’s unaware of it, you should tell him, because you can’t take an already gained victory away from him.

And on another [FAQ page](http://www.catan.com/faq/4613-victory-conditions-may-i-continue-scoring-points-after-having-reached-number-victory-points) you are not allowed to not claim victory to "pad" your score in an official game:

> Victory Conditions - May I continue scoring points after having reached the number of victory points required for a win?

With response:

> This could make sense in a private tournament where the scores from several games are added up. For individual games and official tournaments, the following applies: You have won as soon as you have reached the required number of victory points on your turn – and then the game is over.

So, if you want to run a private tournament with some "house rules", you could, but in an official game the first player to have 10 points on their turn wins, regardless of if they realize it or announce it.

Comment: Thank You for a meaningful response. As I read your response it says over and over "on your turn". If someone has passed their turn without claiming victory, is it fair to claim victory after someone else claims victory "on their turn" which is NOT "on your turn"? Also, concerning the directive to "tell him"; the other players have no way to know "to tell them" IF the win is accomplished by an undisclosed development card that is a "victory point". If in fact you can win without declaring a win "on your turn" with the game continuing, it sure is a bummer for the person who" thought" they won!

Comment: @DavidB. - It doesn't sound like the rules care at all about who "claims"/declares the win.  If it is your turn _and_ you have 10 points then you win, full stop.  If you then allow someone else to start their turn, and they have 10 points, it doesn't matter because you already won when it was your turn.  In a nutshell, the winner is whoever had 10 points on their turn _first_.  Not 'whoever's turn it was when someone realized they had 10 points'.

Comment: Another phrasing: As far as the rules are concerned, there is no such thing as "declaring victory." You just win the game when you have 10 points on your turn.  That's it, the game is over.

Comment: And Kevin, do you agree you win even if you don't know you won until someone else thinks they won? To me, that seems to reward carelessness, stupid and/or asleep at the wheel, so to speak. I had thought maybe the phrase "on your turn" might mean you have to win..... on your turn.

Comment: @DavidB. It doesn't reward carelessness - after all, they had to get to 10 VP somehow - it just doesn't punish it.

Comment: The question then becomes, does a victory point card that has not been played count toward a player's score?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No, according to Mayfair at [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/2491/1706). If you had 10 points visible, you won. If you were holding points secret, you didn't.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede VP card are never "played". The moment you buy a Development card that gives 1 VP, you have that 1 VP. The rules/FAQ say that these cards are simply revealed at the end of the game. You never "play them" to get the points. I know this contradicts what Mayfair was quoted as saying in that other answer, but it seems clear that Mayfair's response is not in line with the actual rules/FAQ, given that they talk about "declaring victory".

Comment: @GendoIkari Every other type of development card must be played to have effect.  The idea that victory points don't would require specific documentation.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede The rule quotes and such are discussed in a few different questions/answers on this site... But it's on Page 7, under Development Cards: "You may only play 1 development card during your turn -- either 1 knight card or 1 progress card.... you only reveal victory point cards when the game is over..." So the game must already be over before VP cards are revealed. And the game doesn't end until someone has 10 points.

Comment: @GendoIkari I see. The distinction between revealing victory points *after* the game is over and the revelation of victory points *causing* the game to be over makes all the difference.